# Ubuntu booting instead of other distro

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I made a triple boot setup with W10, eOS and for the last Ubuntu 19.04, well, the thing is that I made all the installs in BIOS mode, then I create all the partitions for each one, but instead make them separated, I though to install eOS and Ubuntu to share the same /swap partition and /boot partition.

But doing this, must have been overwrite the eOS, and now if I choose in GRUB to boot eOS, the system boot's Ubuntu.

When I install in BIOS mode, do I have to make /boot partition? Is it only for UEFI?

What can I do to fix this? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check your /boot/grub/grub.cfg to fix the right "path" to your systems, choosing the correct media where they are installed, then reinstall grub.

Have a seat to read
man grub-mkconfig
man update-grub

Is highly recommended to instead of manually editing the spoken file, ask your system to rewrite it automatically by "grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg".

I hope you get things working...

Desculpa o inglês. Se preferir falar em português melhor... :P

Comment: I see, so isn't any dangerous to ask grub rewrite at this point? If I run update-grub it finds my Elementary OS directory path along the others.

Comment: If any issue occurs, you will be able to reboot by your distro's USB live media to fix it again. When trying to rewrite grub's config file and update, grub will show you if any error is occuring.